# The report is shown in QueryDesigner but isnt shown in SSRS report page?

Tags: reporting-services

i have a report page that is using a stored procedure.In design view i right-click the Dataset and click Query Designer.I execute the report and get the result.But when i come to preview tab in the report,i cant get the result.My stored procedure is using some parameters,i write some values in query designer for the parameters,and can get the result.Why this happens ?

Comment: You currently have a relatively low acccept rate. Please can you review your older questions, and consider accepting some of the answers to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report will only run directly in the preview pane if all default parameters are supplied.

If you have cascading parameters or other parameters that require you to manually enter a value rather than picking from a drop down, then the report will not be rendered immediately

If you want it to appear, make sure that all parameters have defaults